# What makes Mathematica interpret Plus this way?

Tags: functions

If I write:

```
Apply[Plus, Range[1, 10]]
```

Mathematica understands I want to sum all the numbers in the list and yields the total of the elements of the set. No suppose I do the following:

```
g[x_, y_] := x + y
Apply[g, Range[1, 10]]
```

Mathematica gives me as output:

```
g[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: Because you define your `g` as a function that can have only two arguments, no more, no less. but `Plus` was implemented in a way to support variable number of arguments, in this case, 10 arguments. Read [Functions with Variable Numbers of Arguments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#17118) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

`Apply` simply changes the head of an expression, so that

```
Apply[newHead, oldHead[subexpr]]
```

becomes

```
newHead[subexpr]
```

In particular, in your example,

```
Apply[g, Range[1, 10]]
```

becomes

```
Apply[g, List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

which in turn becomes

```
g[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

after the old head of `List` has been substituted by the new head `g`.

But your definition of `g` only specifies what should be done in the case that `g` receives two arguments. So Wolfram Language does not know how to evaluate the expression

```
g[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and returns it as a symbolic expression.

EDIT

You could simply set

```
g = Plus;
```

to get the output you desire. Alternatively, you could define `g` as follows:

```
ClearAll[g];
g[s__] := Fold[Plus, {s}];
```

I don't see a good reason for doing this, so I am assuming that your question is purely of academic interest.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the output of:

```
TreeForm[Range[1, 10]]
```

[image]

```
Apply[Plus, Range[1, 10]]
```

gives you 55 since, since the Head was List and it got replaced by Plus as this is what Apply does.

Next, you define a two argument function `g`:

```
g[x_, y_] := x + y;
```

and apply it:

```
Apply[g, Range[1, 10]]

g[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

TreeForm[%]
```

[image]

This time the head is replaced by `g`, but it can't do much since it needs two arguments at a time. Let's partition the range in twos.

```
t = Partition[Range[1, 10], 2]

{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}}
```

Now apply:

```
Apply[g, t]

TreeForm[%]
```

[image]

That is not useful, let's try going one level deeper.

```
Apply[g, t, 1]

{3, 7, 11, 15, 19}
```

To see it before evaluation:

```
Apply[Defer[g], t, 1] // TreeForm
```

reveals that `g` is now acting at level 1.

[image]

You can see that function `g` is summing the two arguments being presented to it. I hope this helps you.